# Bootstrap - align multiple collapsible DIVs in navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So my navbar is going to have the search field before the menu items. These are both seperate collabible DIVs so I can have a toggle for each.

The problem at the moment is that there is a large gap between the search bar and the menu items when on desktop view. There seems to be a min-width attribute on it but I'm not sure why or how to get around it.

Can anyone advice how to remove the gap and align both to the left?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap - Prebuilt Layout</title>

    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
      
      
      
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="container" id="accordion">
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Demo</a>
            <div class="navbar-header">
            
            
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSearch" data-pa aria-controls="navbarSearch" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
               <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
            
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbarContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
               <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
           </div>

            
            
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSearch" data-parent="#accordion">
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </form>
            </div>
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent" data-parent="#accordion">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                 <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                       <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                 </li>
              </ul>
           </div>
            
            
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid text-center">
       <h1 class="display-4">Bootstrap with Dreamweaver</h1>
       <p class="lead">Easily build your page using the Bootstrap components from the Insert panel.</p>
       <hr class="my-4">
       <p>This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
       <p class="lead">
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
       </p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">Click outside the blue container to select this <strong>row</strong>. Columns are always contained within a row. <strong>Rows are indicated by a dashed grey line and rounded corners</strong>. </div>
       </div>
       <br>
       <hr>
       <br>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/card-img.png" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                   <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                   <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                   <br><br>
                   <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                   <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                   <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                   <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                   <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                   <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
             </div>
             <br>
             <br/>
             <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                   Featured
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                   <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                   <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                   <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
                </ul>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/card-img.png" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                   <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                   <p class="card-text">Some text to build on the card's content.</p>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                   <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                   <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="card-body">
                   <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                   <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <div class="row">
          <div class=" col-md-4"> Click here to select this<strong> column.</strong> Always place your content within a column. Columns are indicated by a dashed blue line. </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 "> You can <strong>resize a column</strong> using the handle on the right. Drag it to increase or reduce the number of columns.</div>
          <div class="col-md-4 "> You can <strong>offset a column</strong> using the handle on the left. Drag it to increase or reduce the offset. </div>
       </div>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
             <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                   <h3>Adding <strong>Buttons</strong></h3>
                   <p>Quickly add buttons to your page by using the button component in the insert panel. </p>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Info Button</button>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Success Button</button>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center col-md-6">
             <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                   <h3>Adding <strong>Badges</strong></h3>
                   <p>Using the insert panel, add badge to your page by using the badge component.</p>
                   <span class="badge badge-info">Info Badge</span> <span class="badge badge-danger">Danger Badge</span>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <br>
       <hr>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="text-center col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
             <h4>Footer </h4>
             <p>Copyright &copy; 2020 &middot; All Rights Reserved &middot; <a href="#" >My Website</a></p>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you need the output like this? https://nimb.ws/iXQscK

Answer (score 0):

Set your own style.css lower than the bootstrap one in the heading of your html, and then edit it there. HTML reads from top to bottom, so any changes made to elements in your styles.css are losing priority to bootstrap.

```
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Your css sheet -->

<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```